# Can I set up a Raid 0 and access it on Mac + Win 10

Tags: windows, mac, raid, storage, pci-express

I have a Z820 with two OS PCIe SSDs:

1. 960 Pro NVMe (Windows 10 OS)
2. 970 Plus NVMe (MacOS Mojave)

Can I set up a RAID 0 storage array [Highpoint 3740A] using two 4TB HDDs, then access the storage array when I boot either OS?

Answer (score 1):

With hardware RAID controller you can.
Hardware RAID is designed the way, that it creates hardware abstraction.

```
[ HDD1 ] - [ controller ] - [ VHDD (RAID0) ] - OS
[ HDD2 ] /
```

As shown above: RAID controller "sees" your drives. Then you create one or more logical volumes (VHDD) and pass them to BIOS. 
OS that boots sees logical volumes like physical hard drives connected to your PC.

Of course it's hard to give any promises for MacOS running on HP workstation, but generally it should be fine. ;)